# DB2 - Ways to get multiple positions for character in a string

Tags: sql, db2

So I am having the pleasure of working with a very old database that apparently was setup before the invention of normalization. I have been asked to see if I can come up with a way to make it work right.

The first table actually has something like a real primary key.
example:

```
ID, Reason
--- ----------
 1, Write off
 2, Overage
 3, OLH
```

The problem is the other table...

```
CustomerNum, JobNum, Reasons
------------ ------- ---------------------
      42351,     46, X
      32313,    456,    X
      85472,     13,   X    X
```

How are these tables joined in their system? Yup, the position of the X's in the line. So if the X is in the first position, it's the reason 1, second position, reason 2, and so on. It's essentially a flat array. And that wouldn't be to bad actually, if they limited it to 1 X per line... (`LOCATE('X', REASONS) as XINDEX`) but that's not the case. In theory there are 21 possible X's that could be checked on each line.

So I have to give them a recommendation on how to make it work.
One of my first recommendations will be to create a separate table and normalize the tables, however I don't know how well that will go over, or if they would be willing to change their system.
So, I would also like to suggest something like a stored procedure that would be able to go through each line and return the indexes as if they were in a separate table.

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm hopeful.

**EDIT**

So yeah, I'm *really* going to push the linking table.
here's the alternative that I've got working from the suggestions:

```
Select tblCustomers.*, 
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,1,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 1)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,2,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 2)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,3,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 3)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,4,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 4)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,5,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 5)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,6,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 6)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,7,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 7)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,8,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 8)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,9,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 9)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,10,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 10)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,11,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 11)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,12,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 12)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,13,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 13)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,14,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 14)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,15,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 15)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,16,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 16)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,17,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 17)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,18,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 18)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,19,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 19)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,20,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 20)) || ', ' ELSE '' END 
|| CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Reasons,21,1) = 'X' THEN RTRIM((SELECT Reason FROM tblReasons WHERE ID = 21)) || ', ' ELSE '' END AS XPOS 
From tblCustomers
```

I'm going to have to play with Marlin's suggestion a bit to see how much it streamlines it, but one thing I do like about this query is that it shows how ridiculous their current layout is, and why they should change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really pitch the new linking table, but here is either the meat of the stored procedure, or the way to populate the linking table:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerNum, Reasons.ID
FROM Customers, Reasons
WHERE SUBSTR(Customers.Reasons, Reasons.ID, 1) = 'X'
```

Comment: This works for what it does... I'm hoping they normalize though. Thankfully my responsibilities in this end with giving them the possible solutions and not with rewriting everything.

Answer (score 1):

first thing I would do is to create a new column for each possible position of the X (so if there are 10 positions -> 10 new cols) and give those columns meaningful names. then you can write queries easier...